# Issue with "seconds" not shown for editing in date range time picker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

In date time range picker, when the date is edited there is field shown to edit "seconds" (see link 1) but when I use date range picker, there is no seconds shown for editing (see link 2). Can you please let me know what is wrong and what would be solution to show seconds while editing in date range picker?

```
Link 1- Date time range picker
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5fv6bdps/265/

```
Link 2- Date range picker
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rLnycn80/1849/

Comment: First link is only a empty input with an icon.. it is unclear what you are asking. Can you please explain further? Because 1st has the complete bootstrap which styles it and other one has  only a input... really unclear what you mean

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation of [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) add **'timePickerSeconds: true'** to show seconds in the time picker. Please find the working jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/AkshayaKT/swzgpdqy/).

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    timePickerSeconds: true,
    timePickerIncrement: 30,
    locale: {
      format: 'MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:ss a',
      /* "separator": "|" */
      "separator": " - "
    },
    ranges: {
      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove scroll section in your script

```
$(function() {
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    timePickerIncrement: 30,
    locale: {
        format: 'MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:ss a',
        /* "separator": "|" */
        separator: " - "
    },
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
  });

});
```